# In Spark, how do I transform my RDD into a list of differences between RDD items?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

Suppose I have an RDD of integers that looks like this:

```
10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ...
```

(ie there is a stream of different integers)

and modify the RDD so it looks like this:

```
15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75, 85...
```

(ie each item on the RDD is the difference of of the two RDDs above.)

My question is: **In Spark, how do I transform my RDD into a list of differences between RDD items?**

Comment: what exactly is the transformation you want to perform? ie how is a list of differences equal to `15,25,35,45...` for `10,20,30,40,50...`?

Comment: Hi @rennerj2 I feel like I explained it when I said “each item is the difference of the two rdds” and it was sufficiently clear for a person to answer coherently and correctly. Is there anything I can do to make it clearer?

Comment: Looks like you were looking for an average of every two elements in a sliding window across **one** RDD, as opposed to the difference of items in two RDDs. I guess its just a small choice of wording that through me off, but anyways someone understood it enough to answer so it doesn't matter. cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take help of `rdd's` `sliding` function. like below

```
 import org.apache.spark.mllib.rdd.RDDFunctions._

 val rdd=sc.parallelize(List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80))

 rdd.sliding(2).map(_.sum/2).collect

//output
res14: Array[Int] = Array(15, 25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75)
```

Comment: Thank you! I knew it would involve sliding!